# jquery animation while switchig menu on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have code that switches between menu and submenu on hover, but I want short slide-left animation on mouse-in and slide-right on mouse-out.
My template contain this animations (.mk-vm-animate-out-1 and .mk-vm-animate-in-1) so i'd like to use them (but it's not necessary).

My idea was to add class with animation and some dealy and then add classes that shows submenu... but everything that i tried wasnt working... :/

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {

   $('#menu-item-155').hover( 

 function(){ 
  $(this).parent().addClass("mk-vm-animate-out-1");
  $(this).addClass("mk-vm-subviewopen");   
  $(this).parent().addClass("mk-vm-subview");
 },

    function(){ 
  $(this).removeClass("mk-vm-subviewopen"); 
  $(this).parent().removeClass("mk-vm-animate-out-1"); 
  $(this).parent().removeClass("mk-vm-subview"); 
 }
    );

});
```

```html
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-4673"> <a><span>ITEM 1</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-155" class="menu-item"><a><span>ITEM with submenu</span></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu ">
  <li id="menu-item-4792"><a><span>submenu item1</span></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-4718"><a><span>submenu item2</span></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-4718"><a><span>submenu item3</span></a></li></ul>
 </li>

 <li id="menu-item-159"><a><span>ITEM 3</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-159"><a><span>ITEM 4</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why don't you use CSS's `:hover` pseudo selector instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` and `transition` for this

```
.before-hover {
    left:15px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:-1;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.before-hover:hover {
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1;
    visibility:visible;
    transform: translateY(-15px);
}
```

Comment: If I use this, there's some weird glitch - because transform moves with element so it's no longer hovered...

Comment: @KolcasekKolča can you be more specific please, for example you can add a screenshot here

Comment: I added HTML to original post... 
On hover "#menu-item-155" I want to slide-out whole "#menu-main-menu" and slide-in ".sub-menu" - so only submenu will be visible... on mouse-out "#menu-main-menu" should come back...

Comment: @KolcasekKolča, try $(‘#menu-main-menu’).hover() and $(‘.sub-menu’).mouseout()

Comment: @KolcasekKolča so you have to wrap your element in another div